# Random Forest en R

Tags: r

Estoy practicando con el archiconocido reto de Titanic de Kaggle para R y esto es lo que llevo de código pero ahí me he estancado porque me dice que como que faltan valores en el objeto.

```
#Seleccionamos el directorio donde iremos cogiendo los archivos
setwd("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Titanic")
#Cargamos los CSV
Titanic.train <- read.csv(file="train.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
Titanic.test <- read.csv(file="test.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
#Crea una columna nueva para cada tabla, una rellena de FALSE y la otra de TRUE
Titanic.train$iSTrainSet <- TRUE
Titanic.test$iSTrainSet <- FALSE
#Titanic.test tiene una columna menos y la creamos
Titanic.test$Survived <- NA
#Combinamos los dos objetos 
Titanic.full <- rbind(Titanic.train, Titanic.test)
#Como teníamos dos valores sin columna asignada en la 
Titanic.full[Titanic.full$Embarked=="", "Embarked"] <- 'S'
#Creamos el objeto media de edad que es la media de todas las edades y eliminamos todas los valores que sean Not Available 
age.median <- median(Titanic.full$Age, na.rm = TRUE)

Titanic.full[is.na(Titanic.full$Age), "Age"] <- age.median
#Creamos el objeto media de edad que es la media de todas las tarifasy eliminamos todas los valores que sean Not Available 
fare.median <- median(Titanic.full$Fare, na.rm = TRUE)

Titanic.full[is.na(Titanic.full$Fare), "Fare"] <- fare.median

#Categorical casting
Titanic.full$Pclass <- as.factor(Titanic.full$Pclass)
Titanic.full$Sex <- as.factor(Titanic.full$Sex)
Titanic.full$Embarked <- as.factor(Titanic.full$Embarked)
#Dividimos el conjunto de datos en train y en test, en TRUE y FALSE
Titanic.train <- Titanic.full[Titanic.full$iSTrainSet==TRUE,]
Titanic.test <- Titanic.full[Titanic.full$iSTrainSet==FALSE,]
#Categorical casting
Titanic.train$Survived <- as.factor(Titanic.train$Survived)
#Definimos la ecuación de supervivencia y la metemos dentro de una fórmula
Survived.equation <- "Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare + Embarked"
Survived.formula <- as.formula(Survived.equation)
#Instalamos el paquete de randomForest
install.packages("randomForest")
#Cargamos la librería
library(randomForest)
#Error fatal
Titanic.model <- randomForest(formula = Survived.formula, data = Titanic.train, ntree = 500, mtry = 3, nodesize = 0.01 * nrow(Titanic.test) )
```

Error

> Error in na.fail.default(list(Survived = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :   missing values in object

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que el motivo puede ser que tienes valores `na` en `Titanic.train`. En el caso de `Randomforest` tienes algunas opciones para tratar con estos casos. Veamos algunos ejemplos:

En primer lugar tomamos un dataset y le eliminamos algunos datos adrede.

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)

iris.na <- iris
set.seed(111)

## Borramos algunos valores
for (i in 1:4) iris.na[sample(150, sample(20)), i] <- NA
```

Si probamos llamar a `randomForest` con valores `na` en las variables predictoras:

```
# Esto da un error
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris.na)
Error in na.fail.default(list(Species = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  missing values in object
```

### ¿Que podemos hacer?

- Opción 1 omitir los `na` mediante `na.action=na.omit`

  ```
  iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris.na, na.action=na.omit)
  ```
- Opción 2 imputar los valores `na` por la mediana de la columna

  ```
  iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris.na, na.action=na.roughfix.)
  ```

En tu ejemplo, podrías:

```
Titanic.model <- randomForest(formula = Survived.formula, data = Titanic.train, ntree = 500, mtry = 3, nodesize = 0.01 * nrow(Titanic.test), na.action=na.omit )
```

o bien:

```
Titanic.model <- randomForest(formula = Survived.formula, data = Titanic.train, ntree = 500, mtry = 3, nodesize = 0.01 * nrow(Titanic.test), na.action=na.roughfix)
```

También puedes usar `rfImpute()` para "imputar" previamente los valores `na` y poder analizarlos.

Al modificar mi código e introducir lo que tu me has dicho me pone algo así:
 Titanic.model <- randomForest(formula = Survived.formula, data = Titanic.train, ntree = 500, mtry = 3, nodesize = 0.01 * nrow(Titanic.test), na.action = na.omit )
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

> Titanic.model <- randomForest(formula = Survived.formula, data = Titanic.train, ntree = 500, mtry = 3, nodesize = 0.01 * nrow(Titanic.test), na.action=na.roughfix)
>   Error in na.roughfix.data.frame(list(Survived = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  : 
>     na.roughfix only works for numeric or factor

Por el primer error entiendo que tienes variables con valores que no son numéricos ni tampoco son Factores, **Randomforest** intenta convertirlos en numéricos y al no poder emite el error. Esto también lo confirma el segundo error: que menciona que `na.roughfix` solo funciona con objetos numéricos o factores. En resumen: trata de "castear" todas las columnas que uses en la formula a valores numéricos o en su defecto a `Factor` usando `as.numeric()` o `as.factor()`, por el código que publicaste, las únicas que no se han convertido on `SibSp`, `Parch` y `Fare`, desconozco el tipo de dato y si se deben convertir, revisalo por las dudas  . Para un mejor diagnóstico si quieres puedes publicar el resultado de `dput(head(Titanic.train))` en tu pregunta.

Comment: ya he podido solucionar el entuerto. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido de mucho. Un abrazo herma!

Comment: @M.Monte no uses las respuestas para añadir comentarios

Comment: @Patricio Moracho Podrán ayudarme? He seguido las sugerencias, sin embargo se me presenta el siguiente:                                                                         
Error in randomForest.default(formula = formula, data, na.action = na.roughfix.)  
  NA not permitted in predictors

Puede mi dataset estar incompleto en algunos predictores?

Comment: @Calfiao, básicamente el error te está diciendo eso, tienes alguna variable con algún  `NA` , por defecto se emite un error, podrías ignorar los `NA` mediante el parámetro `na.action=na.omit` pero deberías evaluar el efecto que esto provoca.